# Select item in listView, when call indent or toast?

Tags: android, listview

Everything works, but I have a question about "what is the right way"?

I have this Fragment

```
package com.nielyouri.pluff.ui.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.nielyouri.pluff.R;
import com.nielyouri.pluff.adapters.CourseListAdapter;
import com.nielyouri.pluff.providers.WeekProvider;

public class DayFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = DayFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private ListView mListView = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        WeekProvider provider = new WeekProvider();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.course_list, null);

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();

        // Yay a day is given
        if (bundle != null) {
            int day = bundle.getInt("day");

            Log.i(TAG, String.format("Day: %d", day));

            CourseListAdapter adapter = new CourseListAdapter(getActivity(), provider.getDays().get(day));

            ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);

            if (listView != null) {
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

This fragment will call a ListView and add an adapter to it.

```
package com.nielyouri.pluff.adapters;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.nielyouri.pluff.R;
import com.nielyouri.pluff.model.Day;

public class CourseListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private static final String TAG = CourseListAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    private Context mContext;

    public Context getContext() {
        return mContext;
    }

    private final Day mDay;

    public Day getDay() {
        return mDay;
    }

    public CourseListAdapter(final Activity context, Day day) {
        mContext = context;
        mDay = day;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mDay.getCourses().size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.course_items, parent, false);

            viewHolder.course = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.course);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.course.setText(mDay.getCourses().get(position).getName());

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView course;
    }
}
```

When I click on an item in the list, the `getItemId` method will return an id.

Now my main question is:

**The appropriate location in the code where I should toast or intent when I click on an item in my ListView?**

Answer (score 0):

You have onItemClick method.
Here is an example: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/handling-android-listview-onitemclick-event

And you should add this method inside your fragment, for example below this line:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
if (listView != null) {
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Of course it is not a clean architecture approach, but for now I think is enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        WeekProvider provider = new WeekProvider();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.course_list, null);
        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();

        // Yay a day is given
        if (bundle != null) {
            int day = bundle.getInt("day");

            Log.i(TAG, String.format("Day: %d", day));

            CourseListAdapter adapter = new CourseListAdapter(getActivity(), provider.getDays().get(day));


            if (listView != null) {
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "string you want to show" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
});
        }


        return view;
    }
}
```